# Wordpress : Url Rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a url in wordpress so that I can serve up dynamic content based on variables that are passed.  I have a plug in that needs variable data passed into it.  Currently I have:

```
http://xyzsite.com/page/?var1=something
```

this works fine and passes in a $_GET var.  So my next step is to clean up the variable so that it looks like

```
http://xyzsite.com/page/something
```

I have done a few google searches and come accross some site that looked promising but I cannot get any of them to work.  From what I have read, i need to use

```
add_rewrite_tag and add_rewrite_rule
```

After reading through the articles I have added this to my functions.php page:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%var1%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^page/([^&]+)/?','index.php?p=1141&var1=$matches[1]','top');
```

when i navigate to the page http://xyzsite.com/page/something i get a 404 error.  When i navigate the to http://xyzsite.com/page/?var1=something it is still working fine.  So it looks as if my rewrite is not registering or working correctly.

Can someone help me to achieve the above rewrite.  FYI my permalink settings is set to post name if that matters at all.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you check your `.htaccess` file? Perhaps you don't have a `.htaccess` file or it is ignored. If I were you, I would try to do normal url rewriting first (using Permalink Settings), and if this works, only then start with `add_rewrite_tag()` and `add_rewrite_rule()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I̶'̶m̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶r̶e̶g̶e̶x̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶I̶ ̶s̶u̶s̶p̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶i̶s̶s̶u̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶r̶e̶w̶r̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶r̶u̶l̶e̶:̶

```
a̶d̶d̶_̶r̶e̶w̶r̶i̶t̶e̶_̶r̶u̶l̶e̶(̶'̶^̶p̶a̶g̶e̶/̶(̶[̶^̶&amp;̶]̶+̶)̶/̶?̶'̶,̶'̶i̶n̶d̶e̶x̶.̶p̶h̶p̶?̶p̶=̶1̶1̶4̶1̶&amp;̶v̶a̶r̶1̶=̶$̶m̶a̶t̶c̶h̶e̶s̶[̶1̶]̶'̶,̶'̶t̶o̶p̶'̶)̶;̶
```

̶
̶N̶o̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶/̶?̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶'̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶e̶n̶d̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶u̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶p̶a̶g̶e̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶x̶y̶z̶s̶i̶t̶e̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶p̶a̶g̶e̶/̶s̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶/̶?̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶x̶y̶z̶s̶i̶t̶e̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶p̶a̶g̶e̶/̶s̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶.̶ ̶H̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶s̶?̶

**The stroked out text above is wrong, as Gustavo Straube pointed out in the comments. Please disregard that proposed solution.**

My only last advice is to try adding a `flush_rules();` after your last `add_rewrite_rule`, as stated in http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules.

Note that you should be accessing your query vars with `get_query_var('var_name')` instead of trying to access `$_GET` directly.

Comment: That `?` at the end of regular expression means the final slash (`/`) is optional. So it'll work with both `page/something/` and `page/something`.

Comment: Ouch! You're right, @GustavoStraube! This confirms that I'm not a regex expert in any way, though at least I advised it xD. I guess now it's time to edit ;)